# I got error when i use on AWS SSL Activate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

> i am trying to install FREE SSL on my domain. i am using AMAZON
>   hosting and try to install SSL. but i got this error. i don't know
>   what is issue. please anyone help me do this.

```
Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Comment: Have you checked the Apache error logs? What do they say?

Comment: How to check ??

Comment: Google "apache log file location" and you may find https://blog.codeasite.com/how-do-i-find-apache-http-server-log-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing, The error is very clear.

> (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
>   address [::]:80

Port is already occupied either you need to [kill](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277162/apache-fails-to-start-address-already-in-use-but-not-really) the other process that is occupied the port or change the port in the configuration.

Second thing, if you are using AWS then why you are using or want to integrate free SSL? If AWS also provide it for free?

**[Pricing for AWS Certificate Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-billing.html)**

> You are not charged by AWS for the SSL/TLS certificates that you
>   manage with AWS Certificate Manager. You pay only for the AWS
>   resources that you create to run your website or application. For the
>   latest ACM pricing information, see the AWS Certificate Manager
>   Service Pricing page on the AWS website.

So better to put [request on AWS Certificate Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html) and place AWS SSL on top of LB.